# Spring in Kotlin: Reactive Functional Router for Rest & Web

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, router, spring-kotlin

I'm looking for a clear documentation on how I can create a Router for Spring Webflux in kotlin that directs the user for both Rest and web Endpoints.

I made router to do the rest points with no issue. but couldn't do it for the web, always getting an error message of:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve view with name 'index'

```
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultRenderingResponseBuilder$DefaultRenderingResponse.lambda$writeToInternal$1(DefaultRenderingResponseBuilder.java:197) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.springinaction.router.config.WebConfiguration$$Lambda$524/0x0000000800519368@46b9842f [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/index" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
```

I tried to the router in several ways

```
 @Bean
    fun router(): RouterFunction<*> {
        return resources("/**", ClassPathResource("/templates/"))
            .andOther(
                route(GET("/index"), HandlerFunction {
                    ServerResponse
                        .ok()
                        .render("index")
                })
                .andOther (
                    route(
                        GET("/hello"), HandlerFunction {
                            ServerResponse
                                .ok()
                                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                                .bodyValue("Hello Router World")
                        }
                    )
                )
            )
        }
```

and this way as well

```
@Bean
    fun router(): RouterFunction<*> {
        return router {
            GET("/hello") {
                ServerResponse
                    .ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    .bodyValue("Hello Router World")
            }
            GET("/index") {
                ServerResponse
                    .ok()
                    .render("index")
            }
        }
    }
```

same error...
how can I made the router to resolve the `index.html` file and load it from the `/templates` package?
regards

Comment: the logs say you do `GET "/generate"` you have not declared any such handler

Comment: sorry that kept that word, i should have corrected it. because i used several names... i will correct it

Comment: any idea to do it correctly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, just remove the `ServerResponse` and it will work just fine.

```
@Bean
    fun myRouter(): RouterFunction<*> {
        return router {
            GET("/router") {
                ok().render("mypage.html")
            }
        }
    }
```

either this way or nested way or else will work...

```
@Bean
    fun myRouter(): RouterFunction<*> {
        return router {
            accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).nest {
                GET("/router") {
                    ok().render("mypage.html")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```